# core.async machine that loops until a fx returns true

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, core.async

While loading a web site, I often have the need to load code AFTER some other DOM structural event has occurred. Therefore I often end up with a lot of functions that first check if some element exist in the DOM and then do their thing in the event that said element exist.

```
(ns example.core
  (:require
   [cljs.core.async :as async]
   goog.async.AnimationDelay)
  (:require-macros
   [cljs.core.async.macros :refer [go go-loop]]))

(defn register-click-handler []
  (when js/window.document.body
    (goog.events.listen
      js/window.document.body
      goog.events.EventType.CLICK
      #(js/console.log "I was clicked!"))
    true))

(defn loop-until-true [fx]
  (let [c (async/chan)
        f (goog.async.AnimationDelay. #(async/put! c :loop))]
    (async/put! c :initial-loop)
    (go-loop []
      (async/<! c)
      (when-not (true? (fx))
        (.start f)
        (recur)))))

(loop-until-true register-click-handler)
```

I think I like this pattern as it lets me write `fx` that keeps trying until the DOM is in a state where the function can succeed (return true); without having to go through a great deal of ceremony in terms of dealing with retrying (just return true on success).

I am looking for improvements to `loop-until-true`, a function that registers another function to keep executing until that function returns true. I don't want to actually block the execution of the code that might cause `fx` to pass, so I am using a core.async block to IOC the code. This code seems to work, but I am looking for improvements and critics.

Answer (score 1):

`<body onload="f()">` and place your code that listens on click into `(defn f [] …)`.